# Find a finite Gröbner basis for ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

Find a finite Gröbner basis in lexicographic ordering $x \prec  y \prec z$ for ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$, where 
$$ I = \{ f \in \mathbb{R}[x, y, z] \space | \space f(a, -a, 2) = 0 \space \forall \space a \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

---

I only know how to apply Buchberger's algorithm to determined ideals, for example such as $(xy + 2yz, x-y, yz-y)$. But how to find the basis in my case?

Comment: You are given the set of generators. The only difference is that that set is infinite. Not problem, just run the algorithm the same way. There are infinitely many pairs to consider but some options are convenient in this case. For example, I would assume $z>y>z$ and start with the polynomial $z-2$ and (imagine) reduce(ing) all other generators by this. All the remainders are going to be polynomials on $x$ and $y$ only. Then take the polynomial $y+x$ and do the same. Now, all remainders are polynomials on $x$. But the only polynomials on $x$ in the set of generators is $0$.

Comment: This case is simple enough to do this. In a more complicated case you can proceed [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implicitization_of_a_rational_curve), or [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implicitization_in_higher_dimension) when there are more parameters besides $a$.

Comment: Or you could note that $I$ is exactly the kernel of the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z] \to \mathbb{R}[a]$, $f \mapsto f(a, -a, 2)$ - and then use the algorithm for finding a Grobner basis of a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the generators $f_i$ of $I = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$.

Wlog $f_1=z-2 \in I$, so you can remove all the occurrences of $z$ in the other generators. So you can consider all the $f_i, i > 1$ as polynomials in $x,y$.

Wlog $f_2=x+y \in I$. Are there other "useful" generators or $I = (f_1, f_2)$? Consider $f \in I$ and the monomial order $z>y>x$: the remainder of the division algorithm is a $g(x)$ such that $g(a) = 0 \ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$. So $g=0$ and $f \in (f_1,f_2)$.